# Extract the attribute of a tag from Plone site and make it the contents of a tag in theme

Tags: plone, diazo

I'm trying to extract the attribute of a tag in my Plone site and make it the contents of
a tag in my theme.

**The specific usecase:**

I'd like to extract the plone site title from #portal-logo, the markup in the Plone site looks like this:

```
<a id="portal-logo" title="Cool Plone Site" accesskey="1" href="http://mysite">
      <img src="http://mysite/logo.png" 
          alt="Cool Plone Site" 
          title="Cool Plone Site" 
          height="56" width="215">
</a>
```

The title should be inserted between h1 tags in the header tag of my template

```
<header>
     <h1>Cool Plone Site</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
<replace css:theme-children="header h1">
     <xsl:value-of select="//*[@id='portal-logo']/@title"/>
</replace>
```

The key here is **theme-children**. I'd love to be able to use css:select to grab the title attribute, but this works and is still acceptably elegant :)

Comment: CSS only allows you to select elements. You could set a variable: `<xsl:variable name="portal-logo" css:select="#portal-logo"/>` and then refer to it with: `<xsl:value-of select="$portal-logo/@title"/>`. I'm not convinced that it's really any easier though.

Comment: @LaurenceRowe that may be useful in situations that I may need to use the $portal-logo in other rules. Would save repeating myself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the title tag instead? Something along the lines of

```
<replace content-children="/html/head/title" theme-children="/body/header/h1" />
```

should yield the desired results, since the logo's title attribute is constructed from `portal_state/navigation_root_title` anyway.

Comment: The title tag would not work, it combines the page title with the site title. There are other scenarios where this approach may prove useful, so it's worth figuring out a way to extract an attribute and insert into a target tag.

Comment: You are actually right. I had not thought about the title merging.